# How to draw CATransform3D for this layer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, catransform3d

I'm using CATransform3D and CAShapeLayer to create a layer like below
[image]

Here is my code.

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - width / 2, y: center.y - height / 2)
path.move(to: startPoint)

path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + width, y: startPoint.y))

path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + width, y: startPoint.y + height))

path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y + height))

path.closeSubpath()

    let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
backgroundLayer.path = path
backgroundLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
backgroundLayer.strokeColor = boarderColor.cgColor
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = -1 / 500
let angle = 45.toRadians
backgroundLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 1, 0, 0)
```

The output is like below.

[image]

What is the reason for the difference of shape?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is going on, but if you use (0, 0) as the center you will get something that looks more like you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backgroundLayer needs a frame and a position. If these are added, the result is as follows:

[image: result with frame and position]

**Source**

Here a slightly modified version of your code that gives the result shown in the screenshot.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let boarderColor = UIColor.red
        let height: CGFloat = 400
        let width: CGFloat = 250
        let center = CGPoint(x: width / 2.0, y: height / 2)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - width / 2, y: center.y - height / 2)
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + width, y: startPoint.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + width, y: startPoint.y + height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y + height))
        path.closeSubpath()

        let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        backgroundLayer.path = path
        backgroundLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        backgroundLayer.strokeColor = boarderColor.cgColor
        //these two lines are missing
        backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        backgroundLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2)

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform.m34 = -1 / 500
        let angle = CGFloat(45 * Double.pi / 180.0)
        backgroundLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 1, 0, 0)

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
    }

}
```